# Mono 3.0.1 --> Error compiling xsp for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (AWS Linux AMI)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, mono, xsp

Last year i wrote an installation guide on this site for Mono 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86

In the compilation section, there was this part :

```
###################
### Compile xsp ###
###################
cd /opt/mono-3.0/xsp
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr  (the prefix is very important for Ubuntu 12.04)
make
make install
```

I've just created a AWS Linux AMI server with Ubuntu 14.04.  Everything on my installation guide worked perfectly except for this XSP Compilation.

**Here is the error :**

```
configure: error: You need to install 'sn'
Error: Could not run ./configure, which is required to configure xsp
```

Why would i need 'sn' sudendly ???  What do i need to install ???

I tried apt-get install sn      and it still won't work !!!

I'm stuck there.... :(

I do not have a clue how to fix this problem !  Help :)

Comment: You should forget about Mono 3 which is neither a stable release, nor most up-to-date. You should now go with Mono 3.2.8 or 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

The "sn" file isn't a package you download, its a bash script. Below are the contents within the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 077
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS /usr/lib/mono/4.5/sn.exe "$@"
```

I experienced this bug when my paths were different during configure step (--prefix=/usr) for my mono installation and the fastcgi server. Since you're using Ubuntu, you can install a XSP equivalent designed for production by issuing:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-fastcgi-server4
```

It should pick up your mono installation automatically if you kept the default paths during your mono compilation.